# Hello, i have an problem with an with a keyboard input program

Tags: java

When I type the name, it gives me a valid number or a special character. I would like to make it so that the number is not taken into account and is not returned, or maybe it gives an error message.

```
if (nome != null && !nome.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Il nome inserito è:" + nome);
} else {
    System.out.println("Non è un nome valido");
}

while (!nome.contains("\[0-9\]+")) {
    continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

`String#contains()` checks plain text; it doesn't do a regex match.

To do a regex match use `String#matches()`, but note that it requires the *entire* String to match.

The closest working code to yours is:

```
while (!nome.matches(".*\\d.*"))
```

If you want to allow only Latin letters and spaces, consider using:

```
nome.matches("(?i)[a-z ]+") // (?i) means ignore case
```

However your messages suggest you are in the context of Italian, so this may be more useful:

```
nome.matches("(?i)[a-il-vzàèéìòù ]+") // ignore case, jkwxy omitted, add accented vowels
```

The complete code would look like:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String nome = null;
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Inserisci il nome:");
    nome = scanner.nextLine();
    if (!nome.matches("(?i)[a-il-vzàèéìòù ]+")) {
        System.out.println("Non è un nome valido");
        continue;
    }
}
System.out.println("Il nome inserito è: " + nome);
```

Comment: Excuse me, where should "String matches()" be inserted?

Comment: @Daniel see complete code added to answer